# Add number to sorted list recursively

Tags: python

I want to add my_num to where it fits in the given list and I want to solve it by using this structure, however I'm not getting the right results. What can I do?

```
my_lst   = [1, 3, 5]
my_num   = 4

def new_number(lst):
    return lst

def plus_number(n, lst):
    
    def add_number(n2, lst2):
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            if lst2[0] > n2:
                return [n2] + lst2
            else:
                return [lst[0]] + add_number(n2, lst2[1:])
    
    return new_number(add_number(n, lst))

result = plus_number(my_num, my_lst)

print(result)

>>> [1, 1, 4, 5]
```

Edit: changed `[lst[0]]` to `[lst2[0]]` and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Typo.  In `add_number` you have `return [lst[0]] +`... where you meant to use `lst2`.

Comment: You realize that `new_number` is not creating a new list, right?

Comment: Your `new_number` function doesn't *do anything*, btw, simply returning whatever object you pass to it.

Comment: Thank you @TimRoberts that typo fixed it. It should be sorted yes. Thanks again!

Comment: as an aside, `for i in range(len(lst)):` doesn't make sense, the body of your loop always returns on the first iteration

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what should I have instead?

Comment: You should not have a loop at all. Think about it, consider `for i in range(1_000_000_000): if n + 1 == 1000: return 'foo'; else return 'bar'` is equivalent to just `if n + 1 == 1000: return 'foo'; else return 'bar'`

Comment: And also, the *recursion* is doing your looping here

Answer (score 1):

There is already a stdlib method for this, no need to reinvent it:

```
>>> from bisect import insort
>>> my_lst = [1, 3, 5]
>>> insort(my_lst, 4)
>>> my_lst
[1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you I'm learning python and this is an exercise without stdlib

Comment: Part of learning Python is learning to use the right tools. Copying the list every step with `lst2[1:]` is really inefficient. I recommend you use `insort` here, it's much better and there is rarely any good reason to avoid stdlib.

Comment: It's learning for school, it's about grasping concepts, not writing production code

Answer (score 0):

I've two solutions:

1. Using a sentinel, enumerate and insert.

```py
my_lst = [1, 3, 5]
my_num = 4
my_lst.append(my_num) # sentinel
for i, value in enumerate(my_lst):
    if my_num <= value:
        my_lst.insert(i, my_num)
        break
my_lst.pop() # remove sentinel
print(my_lst)
```

2. Using enumerate, insert and else:

```py
my_lst = [1, 3, 5]
my_num = 4
for i, value in enumerate(my_lst):
    if my_num <= value:
        my_lst.insert(i, my_num)
        break
else:
    my_lst.append(my_num)
print(my_lst)
```

If you can't use break, you can circumvent that with a function. Note that this will be trickier for the first function.

Comment: This is suboptimal _O(n)_, using `insort` is _O(log n)_.

Comment: Well, this is the best I can do without stdlib.